Why does monoculture cause lower microbiome diversity and health in bees and how can we fix it?
How can you be sure certain microbes only grow on limited plants, so bees can only swallow limited microbes in a monoculture environment? Why can't bees just evolve to eat or lick dirtier places such as toliets or huamn feces as when wolves evolved to dogs, why can't or humans spread diverse microbes on a monoculture crop and give special growing spray on the plants and the beehives?
Could we just engineer genetically modified bees that can adapt to monoculture?

Welcome Coo. When posting we're required to show evidence of our own researches into the topic. The best thing to look up is the bee's immune-system  - and how they rely on a variety of phytochemicals in order for it to function. Where would they get those. You should edit that in and link to your source.

You're saying some plants can't have all phytochemicals, and bees eat the phytochemicals, and phytochemicals are necessary for health?

No I'm saying that you need to edit the question to show your research. Answering questions in comments is forbidden, but I gave you a hint as to how to look to find the necessary material to find suitable links for your references.

"Why can't bees just eat or lick dirtier places as wolves evolved to dogs...(?)" This is very confusing to me, as one doesn't follow the other. We can't force bees to act in unnatural ways; many past attempts to genetically modify something (even some through selection, e.g. holsteins) have had unanticipated negative consequences. Genetic modification isn't the answer to the enormous problems humans have caused the insect world. If a problem has a human cause, it would benefit from a change in human behavior, not our tinkering with the genomes of our victims.

As far I understand the problem the main cause of decrease in bacteria in monoculture is using pesticides. Onwona-Kwakye M, et al. Pesticides Decrease Bacterial Diversity and Abundance of Irrigated Rice Fields. Microorganisms. 2020 Feb 25;8(3):318. doi: 10.3390/microorganisms8030318. PMID: 32106524; PMCID: PMC7142973.
Also anongoodnurse has good point that you can't force some species act against its' nature.

Technocratic view on the problem solutions are quite common these days. If you look into history then most of the technological solutions has created much bigger problems. Eg. we can say that solving food production problem didn't solve starvation if you look bigger picture and looking into future then we are facing famine unseen because of human population size, climate change and soil degradation.

Also, monoculture isn't about the biome in the monoculture; it's about the nutritional deficiencies associated with being exposed to only one kind of pollen and nectar for long periods of time. Bees don't live for very long; it would be as if you were only allowed to eat oranges your entire life. It's just not a good enough diet.

Domestic honeybees aren't really in trouble. Colony collapse alarms were somewhat overblown. Commercial beehives are trucked around the country to pollinate various crops and orchards during different growing seasons, so monoculture isn't necessarily the concern for honeybees. However, the diversity of wild bee populations suffer when native habitats are converted for other uses. Around 25% of wild bee species are specialist pollinators that might only collect pollen and nectar from one or a few different wild flowers. Take away those wild flowers and the bees die with them.

@MikeyC - Your comment is entirely untrue. It appears you have a lot of reading to catch up on. Honeybees live 5-7 weeks. If they are transported to an orchard (for all intents and purposes a monoculture) or a lavender field, those flowers are almost the entirety of their diet. If in a lavender field, it is the only source of nectar they have for their entire lifespan. That is very bad for honeybees.

This is a good, big but complex question. One issue honey bees face are viral and bacterial pathogen attacks and the low diversity in their microbiome is believed to be a contributory factor. Viral attacks are particularly problematic.
For example Assis de Silva et al 2023 raises exactly the same question that the OP does. It's a huge problem and widely known.
Crop rotation is a strategy to increase the microbiome in the soil and presumably in the plant, thereafter (waving my hands about a bit) in the bee.
The number of soil microbiome studies demonstrating crop rotation are beneficial to the soil microbiome which are in the public sector is very limited (I'm not aware of any). This work has certainly been done in the private sector, but its against employee contracts to report the findings.
Most published rotations concern legumes to increase nitrogen that increases the growth of the cash crop (USDA did a large number of studies in the 1990s on this). Basically here the rhizobia populations in the soil are increasing, albeit not empirically demonstrated via metagenomics.
Ultimately monocultures are about revenue for the crop rather than the bee, so whilst your question is a good one, economically I can not see a farmer rotating their crops on a hypothesis it might give the bee a more diverse microbiome and halt the decline of their populations through pathogens.
Also viruses are, I think, the major pathogen of honey bees and I'm not certain the microbiome of the bee will provide resistance to viral attacks.
Viral attacks were associated with vector-borne infections in bees (mites I think) and targeting the mite is probably the best strategy, but I have no expertise here. How a mite can be differentially targeted in a bee colony is way outside my expertise, I suspect it can't be done.

Nice answer, +1. I think, though, that it's safe to say that monocultures cause malnutrition in bees, which in turn causes decreased immunity to disease of all kinds, so planting a diversity of pollen sources wherever bees are kept/moved to is a reasonable place to start.
